# Extract vectors from ArcGIS MapServer into virtual layer with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, vector, map-service, feature-service

This is the first time I've used QGIS, so bear with me. I have an ArcGISMapServer data source and added one of its layers to the canvas. It doesn't let me customize any of the styles, because I assume QGIS is just pulling down tile images. All of the features have geometry data, so I'd like to extract the polygons into a virtual layer so that I can style them myself. But I'm not sure what query to use.

Is this even possible and, if so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 3):

I tried this on a whim and it actually worked.

ArcGIS MapServer services can apparently also act as ArcGIS FeatureServer services. I just added an ArcGISFeatureServer using the MapServer URL and it started pulling down polygons instead of tiles.

Comment: This isn't always the case unfortunately - it depends on how the particular service is configured.